# Minimum Code needed for Wordpress Query

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering if anyone knows the best way to handle using the minimum code to do a Wordpress query. For example:

I just want a blank white page that runs a custom SELECT query that I create that returns how many posts meet certain criteria.  I'm using WP_Query with custom args to get my results, and in my case I don't need a loop, just the # of results displayed on a blank white screen (for my demo purposes).

```
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
$num = $my_query->post_count;
echo "# of posts is " . $num;
```

I'm assuming I need access to functions.php in both my theme and Wordpress installation.  And I know I could call get_header() and that would setup my database connection, but also render the  section and stuff which I don't want.

Basically just open the DB connection, run the WP_Query and echo the post count.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I found some info that will help, I'm going to start with:require_once(path/to/wp-config.php');
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

Answer (score 0):

Is your test page in your theme ( custom page template for exemple ) ? 
if yes : this code worked for me :

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1&post_type=post');
echo $count = $my_query->post_count;
```

"post_type" args is required and "posts_per_page=-1" to handle all results